# How to do a global search in Eagle

Tags: eaglecad

I received an 8-page schematic from someone else, and I'm trying to make sense of it all.  So I see a net coming out of a chip, and want to know where it goes.  I tried the Tools->Search command.  It doesn't seem to have a way to search for a net, but you can search for a pin.

So I tried that, and it always comes back with "1 pins(s) **pin_name** found!" followed by the sheet number and coordinates of its first occurrence.

But what I want is a global search, so I can find all the sheets where the net is going to in the schematic.  There doesn't seem to be an option for this in the Search dialog, and I couldn't find anything under Help.  A search on Google only pulled up global searches just for libraries.

I am using the latest version, CadSoft Eagle Professional 7.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On second look, I've just accidentally discovered how to do it (or at least in Eagle 6.5, you'll have to test and see if it works in 7.5).

The `find` ULP (which is what the search menu item runs) will find the net with that name, and then just shows whatever is the first wire it finds on a net.

In you instead use the `show` command with the name of what you want to find, followed or preceeded by something else entirely different, it seems to do what you want.

Running the command `show searchterm` where `searchterm` is one or more things you want to find (space separated, wildcards `* ? [...]` allowed) brings up a window which allows you to click between all occurrences of a specific net, gate, or pin (possibly other things):

[image: Show command]

However it seems that if any instances of a net are on the current sheet, then the window does not appear, and instead all instances on the current sheet are highlighted.

In which case to force the window to appear, you have two options:

1. You could add a blank sheet at the end of the schematic. Then to find the signals, switch to the blank sheet and execute the `show` command. This will ensure the window always appears because there would never be any matches on the blank sheet.
2. You could include an extra random string to find which you know doesn't exist. For example `show find searchterm`, would search for `find` and `searchterm`. Assuming `find` doesn't exist on any sheet, then the window will appear even if any instances of `searchterm` appear on the current sheet.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I was looking for.  The find.ulp just brings up the same dialog as Tools->Search.  I never thought to try it without "run" in front of it.  I really like that you can click on one of the items in the list and it takes you to that page.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. I tried to copy what the answer has and it doesn't function.

Comment: @user3308807 Seems the `find` bit was unnecessary, it's just `show`. It also seems that it doesn't bring up the window if any instances are on the same sheet, instead it just highlights them all. I've updated the answer with a workaround.

Comment: Ah, the `find` bit after `show` was what was forcing the window to appear even if nets existed on the current sheet (becuase `find` didn't exist).